# Push Notifications Using Firebase Cloud Functions in Firestore

Tags: javascript, google-cloud-firestore, firebase-cloud-messaging, google-cloud-functions

I am having trouble making a javascript code that will send a notification to the user. I have few questions and clarifications that I want to know:

- Why am i having an error like this.

```
TypeError: Cannot read property 'userID' of undefined
    at exports.sendNotification.functions.firestore.document.onWrite.event (/srv/index.js:8:30)
    at cloudFunction (/srv/node_modules/firebase-functions/lib/cloud-functions.js:131:23)
    at /worker/worker.js:825:24
    at <anonymous>
    at process._tickDomainCallback (internal/process/next_tick.js:229:7)
```

- And about the `tokenID`, how will i implement it? One time insertions when the user sign up? or Every time the user logged in the token id will updated?

**Below is my code on index.js:**

```
'use strict'

const functions = require('firebase-functions');
const admin = require('firebase-admin');
admin.initializeApp(functions.config().firebase);

exports.sendNotification = functions.firestore.document("Buyers/{userID}/Notifications/{notificationId}").onWrite(event => {
    const userID = event.params.userID;
    const notificationId = event.params.notificationId;
    console.log("BuyerID: "+userID);


    return admin.firestore().collection("Buyers").doc(userID).collection("Notifications").doc(notificationId).get().then(queryResult => {
    const notificationMessage = queryResult.data().notificationMessage;
    const notificationTitle = queryResult.data().notificationTitle;

    console.log("Title: "+notificationTitle);    
    console.log("Message: "+notificationMessage);    

    const toUser = admin.firestore().collection("Buyers").doc(userID).get();

        return Promise.all(toUser).then(result => {
            const tokenId = result[0].data().tokenId;

            const notificationContent = {
                notification: {
                    title: notificationTitle,
                    body: notificationMessage,
                    icon: "default",
                    sound : "default"
                } 
            };

        return admin.messaging().sendToDevice(tokenId, notificationContent).then(result => {
        console.log("Notification sent!");
        return null;
            });
        });
    })
});
```

**And here is the sample structure of my database in firestore**
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You're using a very old syntax for Cloud Functions triggers.  [The APIs changed](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/beta-v1-diff) since the beta release years ago.  Update your code to the newer signatures as shown in [the documentation for Firestore triggers](https://firebase.google.com/docs/functions/firestore-events).  Triggers now receive two arguments instead of one.

```
exports.sendNotification =
functions.firestore.document("Buyers/{userID}/Notifications/{notificationId}")
.onWrite((change, context) => {
    const userID = context.params.userID;
    const notificationId = context.params.notificationId;
    console.log("BuyerID: "+userID);
```

If you're following an old tutorial, please notify the author of the tutorial to update it.